# Mangum "Unable to determine handler from trigger event"

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

I'm getting an error "Unable to determine handler from trigger event" when hitting an AWS API Gateway endpoint. The endpoint triggers a lambda, which is using FastAPI and Mangum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda integration in the GET method on API Gateway needs to have "Use Lambda Proxy integration" ticked on.